# Is measuring the speed of light using energy and wavelength cyclical?

Tags: speed-of-light, frequency, diffraction, wavelength, photoelectric-effect

I would like to measure the speed of light by directly measuring the frequency and wavelength of a light source. In order to determine the wavelength, I wanted to use a diffraction grating and the diffraction grating equation. Determining the frequency is where the real problem comes in. The easiest way seems to be by using the E=hf relationship, then using the fact that f=v/lambda to determine the speed of light. Since f is constant regardless of the medium but velocity and wavelength do change in different mediums, I figured that this method wasn't indirectly using the fact that c is the speed of light to prove that c is the speed of light. If anyone can see any flaws in this method or provide a better (experimentally viable and non-cyclical) method of determining the frequency, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks ok, but how will you measure the energy?

Comment: Thanks. My professor suggested using a source of known energy like a Mercury lamp. I'm currently looking into ways of finding the energy of a single photon from a laser as well.

Comment: Now *that* would be cyclical because those energies are found by measuring wavelength.